# How many teams can be formed under the following conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In a class of $30$ students, how many pairs of teams, one football ($11$ players) and one basketball ($5$ players) can form with the condition:

a) no student can participate in both teams

b) at most one student participates in both teams

c) any student can participate in both teams

My attempt:

a)  I think in first ask we do this $C_{11}^{30}C_{5}^{19}$, but one of my friends made like on photograph.

[image: answer_key]

b) $C_{11}^{20}C_{5}^{20}$?

c) $C_{11}^{30}C_{5}^{30}$?

Comment: I guessed that you meant a football team judging by the fact that there are $11$ players on the side.   Please edit your question to explain what you have tried and where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: In a class of 30 students how many pairs of teams, one of football (11 players) and one of basketball (5 players) can form with the condition:a) no student can participate in both teamsb) at most one student participates in both teamsc) any student can participate in both teams

Comment: I solve but i share with someone and he makes me very thought

Comment: Users of this site expect that the person asking a question includes his/her own work on the problem and explains the source of difficulty.  Please edit your question to show us what you have done.

Comment: When you ask a question, people here like a little context. You say you have a solution, what is it? Why are you worried your solution is wrong? Etc.

Comment: I think in first ask we do this C_{11}^{30}C_{5}^{19} but one of my friend made like on photograph

Comment: Your answer to the first question is correct.  Your friend seems to be assigning positions to the players.  Have you attempted the second and third questions?

Comment: c) C_{11}^{30}C_{5}^{30}

Comment: b)C_{11}^{20}C_{5}_{20}?

Answer (score 0):

> In a class of $30$ students, how many ways can a football team with $11$ players and a basketball team with $5$ players be formed if no student can participate in both teams?

Your answer 
$$\binom{30}{11}\binom{19}{5}$$
is correct.

> In a class of $30$ students, how many ways can a football team with $11$ players and a basketball team with $5$ players be formed if at most one student can participate in both teams?

Since at most one students participates on both teams, either no student participates on both teams or one student does.

We calculated the number of ways teams could be formed if no student participates on both teams above.

For the case in which one student participates on both teams, there are $30$ ways to select the student who participates on both teams.  We now need to select $10$ of the remaining $29$ students to complete the football team and $4$ of the remaining $19$ students to complete the basketball team.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{30}{1}\binom{29}{10}\binom{19}{4}$$
ways to select the teams if one student participates on both teams.

Therefore, there are 
$$\binom{30}{11}\binom{19}{5} + \binom{30}{1}\binom{29}{10}\binom{19}{4}$$
ways to select the teams if at most one student participates on both teams.

> In a class of $30$ students, how many ways can a football team with $11$ players and a basketball team with $5$ players be formed if any student can participate in both teams?

Follow the model in the preceding question.  Choose the students who participate on both teams, choose the remaining members of the football team from the remaining students, then choose the remaining members of the basketball team from the remaining students.